# Get parent of parent all childrens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try set display: none on all span in parent of parent select when select is changing.

My html code

```
<div id="product1">
 <div class="block">
  <span>qwerty</span>
  <span>qwerty</span>
  <span>qwerty</span>
  <span>qwerty</span>
  ....
  <span>qwerty</span>
 </div>
 <div class="input">
  <select class="sel">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
several times the same
```

Of course I want set display : none on all span elements in same div id="productX" in is my select.

My don't working jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
            $(this).parent('div').children('span').css('display' , 'none');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test shows you the problem

```
console.log($(this).parent('div'))
```

It returns `<div class="input">` which has no spans as children.

It would be

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('div').find("span").hide();
```

you can use a selector and closest

```
$(this).closest('div[id]').find("span").hide();
```

better would be to add a class

Comment: Thank You its working. I can't accept Your answer because I have low rep.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
        $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('span').css('display' , 'none');
    });
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(this).closest('#product1')` you could just `$('#product1')`.

Comment: Ty but I have many blocks and all has id product1, product2 etc. I must have universal code for structure.

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry forgot to remove

Answer (score 0):

So when a Select changes you want to set display none on all span tags beneath the product1 div right?
From the code you have there it looks like you will get the parent div og the select, which would be the div with the class input. So i guess you would have to get the parent of that div once more and the select all child spans.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **`.parents()`**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('change', '.sel', function() {
            $(this).parents('div[id^="product"]').children('span').css('display' , 'none');
        });
    });
```